# The possibility of getting 'head' in an odd number of flip

Tags: probability

We flip a coin as much as it's needed; What is the possibility of the first `head` to appear in an odd number of flips?

I have an answer for this:

Call the answer **P**. If at the **first flip** `head` appears, we're done. If not, at the **second flip** `head` shouldn't appear. We just checked the first two moves, so we'll assume we just got started. (We'll assume the third attempt is our first attempt). So...

**P = 1/2 + (1/2*1/2*P)**

**P = 2/3**

I want to know if there's some other answer.

Comment: It looks OK to me.

Comment: Or, it's the probability that the first flip is heads or that the first flip is tails, and that it takes an even number of flips thereafter: $P = \frac12+\frac12(1-P)$

Comment: We can also add the probabilities of ending on odd flips: $$\frac1{2^1}+\frac1{2^3}+\frac1{2^5}+\cdots$$ which is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Two comments, both of which are answers :-)